# Can sqlalchemy clauses be evaluated without a database?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I make extensive use of the ORM facuilities in sqlalchemy, so in many contexts, I already have data loaded from the database, and want to check conditions or perform calculations on the python objects that are already loaded;  I also want/need to do more batch oriented tasks that are better expressed by executing sql against the database (and not loading data at all).  I would like to use the same code to express the same calculations for both uses, so that I don't have to bend over backwards for a database connection or write each computation twice (once in regular python, again as queries) and run the risk that they *disagree*.

suppose I have:

```
from sqlalchemy import Integer, Column
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()


class Foo(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'foo'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    bar = Column(Integer)

bool_clause = Foo.bar > 10
int_clause = Foo.bar + 10

a_foo = Foo(bar=5)
```

Is there a way to get

```
>>> something(bool_clause, a_foo)
False
>>> something(int_clause, a_foo)
15
```

without first persisting `a_foo` to a database and then executing the query?  I specifically want a way to express the clause so that it can *also* be used in the context of a database query, but still useful without one.

One option would be to change the clauses to functions:

```
bool_clause = lambda foo=Foo: foo.bar > 10
int_clause = lambda foo=Foo: foo.bar + 10
```

```
>>> bool_clause(a_foo)
False
>>> int_clause(a_foo)
15
```

but I find this to be less readable than the original way the clauses were expressed.

Comment: Can you give some context as to why you would want to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a few ways this kind of thing can be approached.

One way is head on, there is a module in SQLAlchemy used by the Query.update() and Query.delete() methods which does this called sqlalchemy.orm.evaluator.   It's capable only of expressing a very limited set of expression operators:

```
>>> from sqlalchemy.orm.evaluator import EvaluatorCompiler
>>> print EvaluatorCompiler().process(bool_clause)(a_foo)
False
>>> print EvaluatorCompiler().process(int_clause)(a_foo)
15
```

It doesn't do more complex expressions such as `in_()` however we are open to any number of reasonable operations being added to this module if you feel like contributing.

Now the way the use case you have is *usually* done is using [hybrid properties and methods](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/extensions/hybrid.html).   In this use case, we take advantage of the awesomeness of Python in that when we have `<anything>.someattr <some operator> <somethingelse>`, we can swap out `self` and `cls` for `<anything>`.   So your example would be:

```
class Foo(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'foo'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    bar = Column(Integer)

    @hybrid_method
    def bool_clause(self, other):
        return self.bar > other

    @hybrid_method
    def int_clause(self, other):
        return self.bar + other

>>> a_foo = Foo(bar=5)
>>> print a_foo.bool_clause(10)
False
>>> print a_foo.int_clause(10)
15
```

This is actually using the same idea as your suggestion to use lambdas, just expressed more nicely.

The two approaches can be combined as well.   One nice thing about the evaluator is that it handles conjunctions like `or_()` and `and_()`.   Without this, hybrids require that you break up the methods into "instance" and "expression" methods if you need to use something like "and" or "or".

Comment: this certainly answers the question i asked.  I'd like to avoid cluttering up `Foo()` with too many `hybrid_*`'s.  is there a reasonable way to shift them to another class/module and still expect them to work?

Comment: Well they produce python descriptors, which are most at home on a class.  The lambda approach you're already doing is pretty much the same thing.   OTOH the EvaluatorCompiler is something I haven't looked at in years (someone else wrote it) but seems kind of neat.

Comment: oh actually, if clutter is the only concern, I typically do this kind of thing with mixins or abstract base classes.  Like a certain business object implements several mixins that provide sets of hybrids.   I have some of these that have dozens of logical methods on them.  But that still assembles the expressions on the namespace of the class ultimately.